# Proof that the lie derivative of connecting vector vanishes

Tags: differential-geometry

Let M be four dimensional manifold and  $Q$ be a vector field. Associated with this vector field for $s,t \in R$ we have a congruence of curves $x^\mu(t,s)$.By congruence I mean  that for fixed $s_0$, $x^\mu(t,s_0)$ is an integral line of $Q$

Let us pick two curves $\gamma(t)=x^\mu(t,0)$ and $\lambda^\mu(t)=x^\mu(t,1)$ . Between this two curves we have a curve $\tau^\mu(s)=x^\mu(t_0,s)$ such that $\tau^\mu(0)=\gamma^\mu(t_0)$ and $\tau^\mu(1)=\lambda(t_0)$
A connecting vector field $W$ is vector such field that if we have $V=W(\lambda(t))$ then  $V$ is a tangent vector of $\tau(s)$ at $s=0$.

People often says for to $W$  satisfy the condition above we should have $L_QW=0$ where $L$ stands for lie derivative. My proof goes like this.

We choose coordinates such $x^\mu$ such that $Q=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^0}$ then $Q^\mu=\frac{dx^\mu}{dt}$ and so  $x^\mu(t,s)=(t+f^0(s),f^1(s),f^2(s),f^3(s))$  and so
$W^\mu=\frac{df^\mu}{ds}$

Also we have that the lie derivative in this coordinates is
$$L_QW=\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x^0},\frac{df^\mu}{ds} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}\right]=0$$

Is this proof correct?

Comment: I don't get what you are talking about. Could you state more precisely what you are asking? What is "a congruence of curves"? On which space is $Q$ a vector field?

Comment: @Didier I edited my question

Comment: Again: what is an associated congruence of curves? How is it defined? Who is $f$? It may seem obvious to you but I'm not really getting your question.

Comment: No, I'm sorry, the part "A connecting vector field $W$ $[\ldots]$ we have that $\tau(0)=\gamma(t)$ and $\tau(1)=\gamma(t)$." is really obscure to me

Comment: @Didier has the same meaning of  deviation vector for geodesics

Comment: @Didier I edited my question

Comment: $s$ Is a real number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I don't get :

- is "the congruence of curves" an initial datum or an object that is constructed canonically from $Q$? (if the latter, I really don't see how)
- has $V$ to be any tangent field to $\tau$ or is it **the** tangent field $\tau'$ (derivative with respect to the parameter $s$)? If so, there do exist counter examples: take $\overline{V}(t,s) = (t+\alpha)V(s)$ where $V$ is the vector field $\tau'$
- does the fact that $M$ is four dimensional has anything to do here?

---

Attempt of an answer:

It seems there is missing some assumptions, like $C$ being injective / an immersion / an embedding. I suppose that $C$ is an embedding (that is, its image $S$ is a surface) for the sake of simplicity.

Write $\gamma_s(t) = \sigma_t(s) = C(t,s)$ where $(\gamma_s)_{s\in [-1,1]}$ and $(\sigma_t)_{t\in [-1,1]}$ are two families of transverse curves (they form a sort of grid for the surface $S$) and define $Q(s,t) = \gamma'_s(t)$ and $W(s,t) = \sigma_t'(s)$, that are two vector fields on the surface $S$, tangent respectively to $\gamma_s$ and $\sigma_t$. Suppose $Q$ and $W$ are the restriction of two ambiant vectors in $M$. Then, at a point $p = C(s,t)$:
\begin{align}
L_QW (p) &= [Q,W](p)\\
&= [C_* \partial_t, C_*\partial_s](C(t,s))\\
&= \left(C_*[\partial_t,\partial_s]\right)(t,s)\\
&= C_*(0)\\
&= 0.
\end{align}
Because the Lie bracket is *natural* (that is $C_*[A,B] = [C_*A,C_*B]$) and $(\partial_t, \partial_s)$ are tangent to a coordinate system.

Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Q is vector field. Given  a vector $V=Q(p)$ at a point $p$ there is unique curve $\gamma$ such that $V$  is the tangent vector of $\gamma$ at $p$. So $C$ is the set of all this curves

Comment: @amiltonmoreira You should have explained that way before anything else. Also, "there is a unique curve..." I think you are talking about geodesic, and you have not introduced any (pseudo-)Riemannian metric. There is no unique curve tangent to a given vector. You should completely rewrite, slowly, your question: every important information was missing.

Comment: @ Didier  see this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_curve

Comment: @amiltonmoreira I know what an integral curve is but here you did not talk about that, you said "the unique curve tangent to $V$ at the point $p$" which is not at all the same thing

Comment: I meant the tangent vector associated to the vector field